# PowerPoint Add-ins: Insert into a specific x,y position on the slide

Tags: office-js

I'm building a simple content add-in for PowerPoint using modern Office development stack.

Is it possible to insert the content add-ins to specific (x,y) coordinates on a slide?
Ideally, I want to insert the content add-in to all slides to a specific position.

If exact coordinates are not possible, can we use a different  guideline like `TopRight` or `BottomLeft`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible at this time. But it is a great idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).